# Keep getting invalid package error when downloading app from Play store

Tags: google-play-store

I can't download any app from Google Play, I get invalid package message.
I know this is an old problem and I that I have to clear Dalvik cache.
Problem is that I can't down load the file manager to do this.

Comment: Please see: [Package Install via Market sometimes fails and gives seemingly random error message](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15932/16575) and [Error downloading apps in Google Play Store with Samsung Galaxy S3: “Package file invalid”](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36654/16575)

Answer (score 1):

> Problem is that I can't down load the file manager to do this.

You can download a file manager from the browser and install it. [OI File manager avaible from the web page](http://www.openintents.org/en/download) as are many others if you search around.